# Crystal Reports: Putting values from several rows into their own columns?

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, oracle10g, report

I have an Oracle SQL query that returns several rows of data for the same sales order when 'holds' (for review then release) have been placed on the order throughout its life.

In each row generated, a hold has normally been applied; sometimes the hold isn't applied until later in the SO life line, or not at all during one phase of its life line.

There can be up to 4 holds applied at different dates and times. I want to have four hold columns: H1, H2, H3, H4.

I would like to know if it's possible to have those hold values from the sales order rows in their own column?  Meaning, one record row for the sales order (SO) details, but at the end of the record show the four Hold columns - so I have one row and not 3-4 rows.

Example record output, where each time a hold is applied it generates a row:

```
SO1 - several SO detail fields - "SCH" hold applied - date applied - date released
SO1 - several SO detail fields - no hold applied yet a user has generated an action against the SO so a record gets written
SO1 - several SO detail fields - "PLN" hold applied - date applied - date released
SO1 - several SO detail fields - "DWN" hold applied - date applied - date released
```

End result:

```
SO1 - SO detail fields - Hold1 (=SCH) - Hold2 (= null) - Hold3 (= PLN) - Hold4 (= DWN)
```

I don't know how to write in PL/SQL (yet) so I'm wondering if this can be done inside Crystal Reports? Any help is appreciated. Please let me know what else to provide for better clarity.

Answer (score 0):

This is labelled "sql", so I assume a SQL solution is ok.  The following query pivots the four columns:

```
select SalesOrderId,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then hold end) as hold1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then hold end) as hold2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then hold end) as hold3,
       max(case when seqnum = 4 then hold end) as hold4
from (select s.*, row_number() over (partition by SalesOrderId order by ReleaseDate) as seqnum
      from (<your query>) s
     ) s
group by SalesOrderId;
```

I'm guessing what the field names are, but the structure you need would be similar to this.

Comment: Thank you Gordon. Very kind of you. I put together a more detailed picture of the data I have and what I would like to see.  Hopefully it will come out right pasted:

Comment: The paste didn't work; it was too long and formatted badly from Notepad, so I'll put it here in pieces. Initial data in two rows:

SO Nbr Line  Cust  Customer  CoNbr Type  PDD      Status  A/R Hold  Hold  Date Applied  Time Applied  Order Qty  Del Qty
------ ----  ----  -------   ----- ----  ---------  ------  --------  ----  ------------  ------------  ---------  -------
107585 1     8801  ABC Ltd.  106   SLS   26-Jun-13    1      1        SCH   6-Jun-12      31817  5000     0
107585 1     8801  ABC Ltd.  106   SLS   26-Jun-13    1      3        BIH   6-Jun-12      31915  5000     0

Comment: what i would like to see:

SO Nbr Line  Cust  Customer  CoNbr Type  PDD      Status  A/R Hold  Hold1 Hold2  Order Qty  Del Qty
------ ----  ----  -------   ----- ----  ---------  ------  --------  ----  -----  ---------  -------
107585 1     8801  ABC Ltd.  106   SLS   26-Jun-13    1      1        SCH   BIH    5000       0